# Does changing this one line implement persistent keep-alive connections?

Tags: delphi, https, openssl, winsock, keep-alive

After the appropriate initializations, here's an infinite loop to service incoming HTTPS requests, but only one connection per request (and assuming requests need only one read):

```
while TRUE do
  begin  // wait for incoming TCP connection
  if listen(listen_socket, 100)  0 then continue; // listen failed
  client_len := SizeOf(sa_cli);
  sock := accept(listen_socket, @sa_cli, @client_len); // create socket for connection
  if sock = INVALID_SOCKET then continue; // accept failed
  ssl := SSL_new(ctx); // TCP connection ready, create ssl structure
  if assigned(ssl) then
    begin
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock); // assign socket to ssl structure
    if SSL_accept(ssl) = 1 then // handshake worked
      begin
      bytesin := SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
      if bytesin > 0 then
        begin
        buffer[bytesin] := #0;
        // decide on response here...
        response := 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK'#13#10 + etc;
        SSL_write(ssl, pchar(response)^, length(response));
        end; // else read empty or failed
      end; // else handshake failed
    SSL_set_shutdown(ssl, SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN or SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN);
    CloseSocket(sock);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    end; // else ssl creation failed
  end; // while
```

Is changing

```
if ssl_accept(ssl) = 1 then
```

to

```
while ssl_accept(ssl) = 1 do
```

all that's needed to correctly support default HTTP 1.1 keep-alive (ie, multiple requests per connection)?

Comment: Assuming that the entire request will be satisfied in one Read call is a recipe for failure.

Comment: That was done just to keep the code short and not distract from the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  `ssl_new()` and `ssl_accept()` should be called only once per connection.  Once a connection and negotiated an SSL session, there is no need to do it again.  HTTP keep-alives are designed to avoid having to reconnect on each request.  You need to loop your calls to `ssl_read()` and SSL_write() instead.

Also, don't forget to check the client's HTTP version.  HTTP 1.1 clients are expected to support keep-alives by default without having to ask for them.  HTTP 1.0 and earlier clients have to explicitly include a 'Connection: keep-alive' request header instead.  Either way, the server needs to send a 'Connection: close' or 'Connection: keep-alive' response header to inform the client whether the connection is being closed or is being kept open, respectively.

Basically, you need to implement this kind of model (pseudo-code):

```
while True do
begin
  accept an incoming connection...

  initialize SSL...

  repeat
    read a request...
    if not Connected then Break;

    KeepAlive := ((client is HTTP1.1+) and (request['Connection'] = '')) or (request['Connection'] = 'keep-alive');

    prepare reply...
    response['Connection'] := iif(KeepAlive, 'keep-alive', 'close');

    send reply...

  while KeepAlive and Connected;

  cleanup SSL...
  close socket...
end;
```

Comment: this creates more questions than answers, especially since it's unclear what you're doing to determine "Connected".  I'm going to repost this problem as a more general question.  Also note that the server does have the option of returning "Connection: Close" and not bothering with keep-alive.

Comment: Even though a request may ask for a keep-alive, and the response may honor it, that does not mean the connection is actually guaranteed to stay connected before the next request arrives.  The connection may be passing through a firewall/router that closes the connection if it is left idle too long between requests, or the client itself may decide to do that on its end.  OpenSSL will tell you if a connection has been closed when you try to read from or write to it.  I have adjusted my pseudo-code model accordingly.

Comment: Because connections and requests aren't guaranteed, I posted the more general problem as question 6656090.  I haven't been able to avoid getting stuck in SSL_read with blocking sockets...